# Would it be possible to build an engine twice the size of the Trent 900?

Tags: jet-engine, turbofan, airbus-a380

Would it be possible to build an engine twice the size of the Trent 900 in terms of physical size, i.e. doubling the diameter?

Let's assume that it's feasible to build an aircraft tall enough to install the engines. I will go on to ask about the extra heat at the engine core or hot sections of the engines but to run such an engine, would current materials be able to tolerate the extra heat? Would the larger fans tolerate the extra stresses if the diameter doubled?

Comment: Won’t be able to answer this myself, but do you mean twice the physical size (in terms of fan diameter etc.), twice the volume/weight, or twice the thrust? I assume that will make quite a difference in feasability.

Comment: Sure, just open up the drawing files, scale by a factor of 2, and then send it off to production.

Comment: @RonBeyer it'll only be 8 times heavier, what could possibly go wrong?

Comment: @fooot Plus they would have to put the aircraft on stilts to get the engine under the wing

Comment: *"As incomes rise, I think jumbos like the A380 would sell tickets at a premium..."* The A380 has problems selling tickets at all, much less "at a premium". If Emirates doesn't order more aircraft, Airbus will most likely halt the A380 production only 10 years after its introduction. The 747-800 is having similar problems as it isn't being flown in passenger service by many operators anymore.

Comment: People that buy luxury goods are not price sensitive

Comment: @securitydude5 Even if they aren't, Airbus/Boeing is, and isn't going to maintain production of the jet for 1 or 2 customers/aircraft.

Comment: 1 or 2 customers of Airbus or Boeing are not the entire Luxury Air travel market.  Even if they were, the market is much bigger than they are currently serving & so if those customers can make super profits with those jets serving the entire market &demanding more because the market is larger, then it would make sense to continue making the air craft. Afterall there were development costs in the beginning. In any case the jets could not achieve economies of scale because thy have to compete with fuel efficient geared turbo fans. continued...

Comment: ...continued Who knows latest developments converting Co2 in the artmosphere, at a much lesser cost could make fuel a lot more cheaper

Comment: "*it would make sense to continue making the aircraft*"... What makes sense is to sell the aircraft. That's what covers the salaries. Airbus had plans for extended versions of the A380, they will probably never been built.

Comment: If Airbus is selling the A380 profitably and those that buy the A380 are able to use it profitably as anticipated or even better, they will be able to pay salaries and continue to demand the Airbus A380 and it will make sense for Airbus to continue making the aircraft.  Remember its the business class and 1st class passengers that subsidize the seats of he economy class and make air travel affordable for them despite their numbers. Creativity on the side of those buying the A380 for use i.e more luxury and prestige premium service, will keep the aircraft in manufature

Comment: "*If Airbus is selling the A380 profitably and those that buy the A380 are able to use it profitably as anticipated*". Indeed this is the idea behind aircraft marketing, and for that matter behind any B2B product, but we know [this is not the case](https://www.quora.com/Is-the-Airbus-A380-a-profitable-aircraft-for-Emirates) due to the anticipated hub deployment in airlines which has not materialized since the plane was designed. Wealthy people are likely those less interested in the hub (mass) mode, they want customized services.